# Dynamic form passing data (coldfusion and query)

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a simple message page where people can react on a specific message. The code:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'save_comment.cfm',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    });
    </script>

    <cfquery datasource="#ns#" name="getdata">
     select text, timeline_id
     from timeline
     order by t_datum desc
     </cfquery>

     <cfoutput query="getdata">
     <p>#text#</p>
     <cfform>
     <cfinput type="hidden" value="#timeline_id#" name="#timeline_id#">
     <cfinput type="text" name="comment"><input type="submit">
     </cfform>
     </cfoutput>
```

Now the problem is that the form is dynamic. So if I submit some comment the value of the hidden form field timeline_id is i.e. 3,4,5,7. Normaly I could send the value like this:

```
     <cfform action="save_comment.cfm?timeline_id=4>
```

but the form is submit with query, so without a page reload.

Any idea's on this?

Thanks!

Comment: As I said in another post of yours... Don't use cfform.  There is no upside to using it.  The only thing it will give you is baldness from pulling your hair out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your form fields something unquie (see below) then you can loop through the field list and match the comments with the ids and it will be a bit easier to put things together.

```
  <cfoutput query="getdata">
     <p>#text#</p>
     <cfform>
     <cfinput type="hidden" value="#timeline_id#" name="tid_#timeline_id#">
     <cfinput type="text" name="tid_#timeline_id#_comment"><input type="submit">
     </cfform>
  </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Why add the `timeline_id` value to each form field? As long as you have the hidden form field, it is not really necessary?

Comment: I just find that if there is more than one it is an easy way to match everything up.  In the case above since there is only one field `comment` I wouldn't even bother with the hidden field at all.  As always with CF there are several ways to do everything, this just happens to be a method that has worked for me many times in the past.

Comment: Just seems like extra processing of the form fields by putting the value into the form field names themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a hidden form field with the name `timeline_id` and set it to the value you need.

Such as

```
<form ....>
    <input type="hidden" name="timeline_id" value="#timeline_id#" />
    More form stuff here.....
</form>
```

Notice that I removed the `cfform` and `cfinput`. You should not use them, they cause more issues than they are worth.